# Oracle failed to search like with % included

Tags: oracle

I failed to search users where its suffix are `%IL`, for example `JohnSmith%IL`

I tried condition `like '%\%IL'` as [suggested](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_special_characters_like_sql_query.htm)

> For another example, assume that we want to seek columns that contain a percent sign (%).  Here we must leave the front and % while escaping the middle percent sign:
>
> ```
> where
>   mycol like '%\%%';
> ```

Obviously both `'%IL'` `'%%IL'` return IL suffix and this isn't what I need

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must define explicite [`ESCAPE` character](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Pattern-matching-Conditions.html#GUID-0779657B-06A8-441F-90C5-044B47862A0A)

```
  mycol like '%\%IL' ESCAPE '\';
```